# Readonly properties with multiple 'constructors' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm running up against an issue in Typescript that I can't find an elegant solution to...

I want to use readonly properties, but they don't seem to be compatible with a multiple 'constructors'.

I'm using multiple constructor because my objects can be created directly, or instantiated from a JSON store. Also I want to have control over the creation API (e.g. creating a UUID on first creation).

My base class looks like:

```
class UserEvent {
    protected constructor(
        readonly uuid: string,
        readonly creationDate: Date,
    ) {}

    static create() {
        return new this(uuid(), new Date());
    }

    static fromJSON(jsonTree) {
        return new this(jsonTree.uuid, jsonTree.creationDate);
    }
    toJSON(): any {
        return {
            uuid: this.uuid, 
            creationDate: this.creationDate.toJSON(),
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to subclass this and add some properties-

```
class OrderedPizzaEvent extends UserEvent {
    private constructor(
        uuid: string,
        creationDate: Date,
        readonly pizzaFlavour: string,
        readonly pizzaSize: number,
    ) {
        super(uuid, creationDate);
    }

    static create(options: {pizzaFlavour: string, pizzaSize: number}) {
        const instance = super.create();
        instance.pizzaFlavour = options.pizzaFlavour;
        instance.pizzaSize = options.pizzaSize;
        return instance;
    }

    static fromJSON(jsonTree) {
        const instance = super.fromJSON(jsonTree);
        instance.pizzaFlavour = jsonTree.pizzaFlavour;
        instance.pizzaSize = jsonTree.pizzaSize;
        return instance;
    }
    toJSON() {
        const result = super.toJSON();
        result.pizzaFlavour = this.pizzaFlavour;
        result.pizzaSize = this.pizzaSize;
        return result;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because the readonly properties are not set the constructor. But I can't call the constructor with the right arguments while using the super implementation of `create()` and `fromJSON()`.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This works, although, it's not very pretty/clean:

```
class UserEvent {
    protected constructor(
        readonly uuid: string,
        readonly creationDate: Date,
    ) {}

    static create() {
        return new this("KEY", new Date());
    }

    static fromJSON(jsonTree) {
        return new this(jsonTree.uuid, jsonTree.creationDate);
    }
    toJSON(): any {
        return {
            uuid: this.uuid, 
            creationDate: this.creationDate.toJSON(),
        }
    }
}

class OrderedPizzaEvent extends UserEvent {
    private constructor(
        uuid: string,
        creationDate: Date,
        readonly pizzaFlavour: string,
        readonly pizzaSize: number,
    ) {
        super(uuid, creationDate);
    }

    static createOrderedPizzaEvent(options: { pizzaFlavour: string, pizzaSize: number }) {
        return this.createInstance(super.create(), options);
    }

    private static createInstance(temp: UserEvent, options: { pizzaFlavour: string, pizzaSize: number }) {
        return new this(temp.uuid,
            temp.creationDate,
            options.pizzaFlavour,
            options.pizzaSize);
    }

    static fromJSON(jsonTree) {
        const instance = super.fromJSON(jsonTree) as OrderedPizzaEvent;
        return this.createInstance(instance, instance);
    }

    toJSON() {
        const result = super.toJSON();
        result.pizzaFlavour = this.pizzaFlavour;
        result.pizzaSize = this.pizzaSize;
        return result;
    }
}
```